# Frequently occurred unexpected exception in netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am using Netbeans 8.2 on windows7 64-bit with jdk8.

Frequently i got unexpected exception in netbeans.

### [image]

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 >= size()=1
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinTokenList.tokenList(JoinTokenList.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinLexerInputOperation.tokenList(JoinLexerInputOperation.java:215)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinLexerInputOperation.fetchActiveTokenList(JoinLexerInputOperation.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinLexerInputOperation.createJoinToken(JoinLexerInputOperation.java:272)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinLexerInputOperation.createDefaultTokenInstance(JoinLexerInputOperation.java:237)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.LexerInputOperation.createToken(LexerInputOperation.java:318)
    at org.netbeans.spi.lexer.TokenFactory.createToken(TokenFactory.java:105)
    at org.netbeans.spi.lexer.TokenFactory.createToken(TokenFactory.java:89)
    at org.netbeans.lib.html.lexer.HtmlLexer.token(HtmlLexer.java:1580)
    at org.netbeans.lib.html.lexer.HtmlLexer.token(HtmlLexer.java:1518)
    at org.netbeans.lib.html.lexer.HtmlLexer.resolveValueToken(HtmlLexer.java:1501)
    at org.netbeans.lib.html.lexer.HtmlLexer.nextToken(HtmlLexer.java:1429)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.LexerInputOperation.nextToken(LexerInputOperation.java:215)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinTokenList.init(JoinTokenList.java:691)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinTokenList.create(JoinTokenList.java:99)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenListList.checkCreateJoinTokenList(TokenListList.java:172)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenListList.(TokenListList.java:131)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenHierarchyOperation.tokenListList(TokenHierarchyOperation.java:498)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenSequenceList.(TokenSequenceList.java:109)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenHierarchyOperation.tokenSequenceList(TokenHierarchyOperation.java:449)
    at org.netbeans.api.lexer.TokenHierarchy.tokenSequenceList(TokenHierarchy.java:229)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher.getMIMETypesOnLine(EditorContextDispatcher.java:348)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher.getMIMETypesOnCurrentLine(EditorContextDispatcher.java:307)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[catch] at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ActionsProvider$ContextAware.isCurrentMIMETypeIn(ActionsProvider.java:407)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ActionsProvider$ContextAware.isEnabled(ActionsProvider.java:278)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.ActionsManager.isEnabled(ActionsManager.java:407)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.ui.actions.DebuggerAction.isEnabled(DebuggerAction.java:133)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.ui.actions.DebuggerAction.access$000(DebuggerAction.java:73)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.ui.actions.DebuggerAction$Listener.actionStateChanged(DebuggerAction.java:426)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.ActionsManager.fireActionStateChanged(ActionsManager.java:576)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.ActionsManager.access$1000(ActionsManager.java:68)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.ActionsManager$MyActionListener.actionStateChange(ActionsManager.java:809)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ActionsProviderSupport.fireActionStateChanged(ActionsProviderSupport.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ActionsProviderSupport.setEnabled(ActionsProviderSupport.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.javascript.debugger.breakpoints.BreakpointActionProvider.propertyChange(BreakpointActionProvider.java:139)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$PropertyChange.propertyChange(WeakListenerImpl.java:215)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher.firePropertyChange(EditorContextDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher.access$2000(EditorContextDispatcher.java:122)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher$EventFirer.run(EditorContextDispatcher.java:1011)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)

---

[image]

[image]

---

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 >= size()=1
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinTokenList.tokenList(JoinTokenList.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinLexerInputOperation.tokenList(JoinLexerInputOperation.java:215)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinLexerInputOperation.fetchActiveTokenList(JoinLexerInputOperation.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinLexerInputOperation.createJoinToken(JoinLexerInputOperation.java:272)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinLexerInputOperation.createDefaultTokenInstance(JoinLexerInputOperation.java:237)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.LexerInputOperation.createToken(LexerInputOperation.java:318)
    at org.netbeans.spi.lexer.TokenFactory.createToken(TokenFactory.java:105)
    at org.netbeans.spi.lexer.TokenFactory.createToken(TokenFactory.java:89)
    at org.netbeans.lib.html.lexer.HtmlLexer.token(HtmlLexer.java:1580)
    at org.netbeans.lib.html.lexer.HtmlLexer.token(HtmlLexer.java:1518)
    at org.netbeans.lib.html.lexer.HtmlLexer.resolveValueToken(HtmlLexer.java:1501)
    at org.netbeans.lib.html.lexer.HtmlLexer.nextToken(HtmlLexer.java:1429)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.LexerInputOperation.nextToken(LexerInputOperation.java:215)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinTokenList.init(JoinTokenList.java:691)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.JoinTokenList.create(JoinTokenList.java:99)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenListList.checkCreateJoinTokenList(TokenListList.java:172)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenListList.(TokenListList.java:131)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenHierarchyOperation.tokenListList(TokenHierarchyOperation.java:498)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenSequenceList.(TokenSequenceList.java:109)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.TokenHierarchyOperation.tokenSequenceList(TokenHierarchyOperation.java:449)
    at org.netbeans.api.lexer.TokenHierarchy.tokenSequenceList(TokenHierarchy.java:229)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher.getMIMETypesOnLine(EditorContextDispatcher.java:348)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher.getMIMETypesOnCurrentLine(EditorContextDispatcher.java:307)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[catch] at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ActionsProvider$ContextAware.isCurrentMIMETypeIn(ActionsProvider.java:407)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ActionsProvider$ContextAware.isEnabled(ActionsProvider.java:278)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.ActionsManager.isEnabled(ActionsManager.java:407)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.ui.actions.DebuggerAction.isEnabled(DebuggerAction.java:133)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.ui.actions.DebuggerAction.access$000(DebuggerAction.java:73)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.ui.actions.DebuggerAction$Listener.actionStateChanged(DebuggerAction.java:426)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.ActionsManager.fireActionStateChanged(ActionsManager.java:576)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.ActionsManager.access$1000(ActionsManager.java:68)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.ActionsManager$MyActionListener.actionStateChange(ActionsManager.java:809)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ActionsProviderSupport.fireActionStateChanged(ActionsProviderSupport.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ActionsProviderSupport.setEnabled(ActionsProviderSupport.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.javascript.debugger.breakpoints.BreakpointActionProvider.propertyChange(BreakpointActionProvider.java:139)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$PropertyChange.propertyChange(WeakListenerImpl.java:215)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher.firePropertyChange(EditorContextDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher.access$2000(EditorContextDispatcher.java:122)
    at org.netbeans.spi.debugger.ui.EditorContextDispatcher$EventFirer.run(EditorContextDispatcher.java:1011)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)

---

After this error occured "ENTER" key not working in netbeans. That means i could not enter a new line by using keyboard. Other keys are working fine.

```
I had reinstalled netbeans8.2. Still the problem existing.
```

Can you suggest any other free php editor?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you don't use [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)?

Comment: What about 'Atom'